# accessing input tag values from html in backend using post method

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Hi guys i am new to html and javascript. my application is to create a table from a list of list went from backend, after creating them dynamically(as length of the list is not known) i need to access some particular values of the table in python backend, when i tried to do this i am able to fetch the value in backend, but the value is not the desired value. The value which it returns is the last element of that table.

given below is my code

```
{% for result in list1 %}
 <tr id="tr_id">
    <form id="listOfSearch{{result.0}}" name="listOfSearch" method="post" action="/fetch_candid/"> 
    <form id="listOfSearch{{result.0}}" name="listOfSearch" method="post" action = "/fetch_candid/">

     <td>
    <a href="#" onclick="document.forms['listOfSearch{{result.0}}'].submit();">{{result.0}}
    <input name="uniqID" value="{{result.0}}" id="IdField" type="hidden" >
    </a></td>

    <input  name="save" value="0" type="hidden">

    <input  name="listresult" value="{{list1}}" type="hidden">
     <input type="hidden" id="statusofresume123" name="statusofresume123" value="{{sres}}">
      <input type="hidden" id="Client1" name="Client1" value="{{client}}">
      <input type="hidden" id="ReqId1" name="ReqId1" value="{{reqid}}">
      <input type="hidden" id="only_skills" name="only_skills" value="{{only_skills}}">
      <input type="hidden" id="mbno" name="mbno" value="{{mbno}}">
     <input type="hidden" id="ReqId" name="ReqId" value="{{reqid4}}">
      <input type="hidden" id="Client" name="Client" value="{{client2}}">
       <input type="hidden" id="Name" name="Name" value="{{Name}}">
       <input type="hidden" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" value="{{Date1}}">
       <input type="hidden" id="datepicker1" name="datepicker1" value="{{Date2}}">
       <!-- <form id="listOfSearch{{result.0}}" name="listOfSearch" method="post" action="/fetch_candid/"> -->
    <td style="padding:5px; width:50px;">


    <select style="padding:5px; width:102%;"  onchange="savestate({{result.0}});" class="select11" id="status8" name="status8" title="Choose Status">
     <option id="status8"  name="status8" >{{result.1}}</option>


     {% if result.1 == "HR_Interview" %}

      <option id="status8"  name="status8">COL</option>


      {% elif result.1 == "Internal_Interview" %}

      <option id="status8"  name="status8">HR_Interview</option>
      <option id="status8"  name="status8">COL</option>


      {% elif result.1 == "COL" %}

      <option id="status8"  name="status8">CS</option>


      {% elif result.1 == "CI" %}

      <option id="status8"  name="status8">CIS</option>


      {% elif result.1 == "CIS" %}

      <option id="status8"  name="status8">Joining</option>



     {% elif result.1 == "CS" %}

      <option id="status8"  name="status8">CI</option>


      {% elif result.1 == "Line_up" %}

      <option id="status8"  name="status8">Internal_Interview</option>
       <option id="status8"  name="status8">HR_Interview</option>
       <option id="status8"  name="status8">COL</option>

     {% endif %}

      </select>
       <input class="css_save1" type="submit" name="save" value="Save" onclick = "function9(this);">
       <input type="hidden" id="name" name="name" value={{name}}>

<input name="uniqID1" value="{{result.0}}" id="IdField" type="hidden" >
<input type="hidden" id="name" name="name" value={{name}}>
</td>

 <!-- </form>  -->


    <td class="reqid1">{{result.2}}</td>
    <td>
    {{result.3}}
    <input name="Client18" id="Client18" type="hidden" value="{{result.3}}">
    </td>
    <td>
    {{result.4}}
    <input name="name18" id="name18" type="hidden" value="{{result.4}}">
    </td>
    <td>{{result.5}}</td>
    <td>{{result.6}}</td>
    <td>{{result.7}}</td>
    <td>{{result.8}}</td>
    <td>{{result.9}}</td>
    <td>{{result.10}}</td>
    <td>{{result.11}}</td>
    <td>{{result.12}}</td>
    <td>{{result.13}}</td>
    <td>{{result.14}}</td>
    <td>{{result.15}}</td>
    <td>{{result.16}}</td>
    <td>{{result.17}}</td>

<input type="hidden" id="name" name="name" value={{name}}>
      </form>

<script>
    function function9(x)
    {
    var id = $(x).closest("tr").find('td:eq(1)').find("#status8 option:selected").text();
    var Client18 = $(x).closest("tr").find('td:eq(3)').text();
    var name18 = $(x).closest("tr").find('td:eq(4)').text();
    console.log("fetched value>>>",id,Client18,name18);         
         if (id == "COL")        
                {
                var r=confirm("Do you want to generate COL NOW ?");
                    if (r == true)
                    {
                    alert("before");
                    document.getElementById("listOfSearch{{result.0}}").action ="/hrpage/";
                    document.getElementById("listOfSearch{{result.0}}").method = 'POST';
                    document.getElementById("listOfSearch{{result.0}}").submit();
                    alert("after");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    document.getElementById("listOfSearch{{result.0}}").submit();
                    }
                }
        else
                {
                document.getElementById("listOfSearch{{result.0}}").submit();
                }
        <!-- return response; -->
    }
</script>
```

this is a django application
 my application is when i press on the save button which is formed in every row i need to get that particular row's client name and candidate name
kindly help me with this

Comment: Could you provide a sample of generated code that doesn't work as you wish?

Comment: @jsruok you want my python file? or a snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help you. First i see in your code two  tags, but you only you close one. That's wrong.

What i would do is to put the form outside of the table and to use two hidden inputs and fill it with javascript code. Pass to the javascript function the client and name in each row:

function9( '{{client}}', '{{name}}' );

the function only have to set the client and name values to the hidden input with jquery and call to the submit form.

You can use the browser developer tools (F12) for see what parameters is being sending to the server.

Good luck.

Comment: I cant do this as i am trying to submit two different forms depending on different conditions so i need to write in a single form and send the values collected @dasolma